# The config property debezium.sink.type is required but it could not be found in any config source

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, debezium, debezium-server

I am trying to build this architecture where:

> (the source: AWS RDS Postgres) + (Debezium Server) + (Kinesis
> Firehose)

my database is running and the kinesis firehose is also there and running and I have configured both of them. I have also put the credentials in a credentials text file on my local machine.

Here are the application properties that I have:

```
debezium.sink.type=kinesis
debezium.sink.kinesis.region=eu-central-1
debezium.sink.kinesis.credentials.profile=credentials

debezium.source.connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
debezium.source.offset.storage.file.filename=data/offsets.dat
debezium.source.offset.flush.interval.ms=0
debezium.source.database.hostname=<the_link_to_the_endpoint>
debezium.source.database.port=5432
debezium.source.database.user=postgres
debezium.source.database.password=postgres
debezium.source.database.dbname=Linda
debezium.source.database.server.name=aws-private
debezium.source.database.schemas.enable=false
debezium.source.plugin.name=pgoutput
debezium.source.schema.include.list=student
debezium.source.topic.prefix=PostgreSQL_server
```

the docker command I am trying to run is:

```
docker run -it --name debezium -p 8080:8080 -v $PWD/conf:/debezium/conf -v $PWD/data:/debezium/data debezium/server
```

The error I am receiving is:

> Please check you have a correct Debezium server config in
> /debezium/conf/application.properties or required properties are
> defined via system or environment variables.

I am running this docker image on my local machine in the ~ directory on Windows

I have created two `application.properties`, one in `conf/application.properties` and the other one is in `debezium/conf/application.properties`, but none of them work.

I have also properly described `debezium.sink.type=kinesis`

The very same setup worked with `Pulsar` and `Postgres` and the server was running, but when I am trying to define kinesis as the type of sink, I am having trouble.

Now, that is the error I am receiving:

> **Failed to load mandatory config value 'debezium.sink.type'. Please check you have a correct Debezium server config in
> /debezium/conf/application.properties or required properties are
> defined via system or environment variables.**

Does anybody knows how to solve this issue ?

thanks a lot